# Use rewrite rule by query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I make that if the `QUERY_STRING` matches something it would use that rule?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} uri=admin
ReqriteRule ^admin\?(.*)/?$ index.php?uri=admin&q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Eg. `http://localhost/admin?poll/new`
After the `?` should be the paramater `q`, the the query would be `uri=admin&q=poll/new`

Any idea on how I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: just answered same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703552/rewriting-dynamic-urls/7774701#7774701 have a look it should be enough

Comment: But how can I rewrite this `?uri=admin&q=poll/new` to `admin?poll/new` ? Long time since I worked with mod-rewrite, so I didn't understand much of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it happens that your problem is more simple than the link I gave you as you do not want any analysis on the query string content.

If you use this single line:

```
RewriteRule ^admin index.php?uri=admin&q= [L,QSA]
```

Where QSA mean append the query string to the result. You will obtain an internal redirection to:

```
index.php?uri=admin&q=&poll/new
```

Which is not OK, this is because the way you use argument (`admin?poll/new`) is not the standard way. So it seems we'll need to capture the query string content and put it by hand on the rewriteRule. This should work (if you need it only for /admin url):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} admin [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php?uri=admin&q=%1 [L]
```

Where %1 is the first parenthesis match in the RewriteCond :`(.*)`, meaning everything in the query string, the query string being anything after the question mark. So in fact this allows `admin?poll/new` but also `admin?poll/new&foo=toto`, giving  `index.php?uri=admin&q=poll/new&foo=bar`