# Htaccess redirect is not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am just tring to write a simple url redirect and I tried to do with the below code, Everyline works except the line which starts with **Redirect 302**, what I am tring to do is make this line work.

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+taksit\.asp\?[^\s&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]

**Redirect 302 /mikrometreler/%C4%B0%C3%A7-%C3%A7ap-mikrometresi?sort=p.price&order=ASC http://www.hirdavatdeposu.com/mikrometre/ic-cap-mikrometresi**

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\_(.*)$ $1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

What can be the reason that this is not working ?

Comment: May be using .htaccess is not allowed in httpd.conf?

Comment: No because I have other parts in my .htaccess, and they are working.

Comment: Try http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0):

First the Redirect instrauction is not managed by [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) but my [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html). So you de not need the RewriteEngine to be started.

Now looking at [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) documentation we can see the syntax is:

```
Redirect [status] /path http://full_uri
```

So try something like:

```
Redirect 302 /asdasd/asdasd http://www.mysite.com/newurl
```

And when it works try to alter the 302 to 301, as 301 are not requested by browsers after first answer, so they're harder to debug.

**EDIT**

Your question is a lot more different now :-)

Try:

- remove the query string part from the path of the Redirect command (the query string part is everything after the ?, a path does not contain the ? and theses arguments)
- try RedirectMatch instead of Redirect if you want to match on an expression
- if your problem is not resolded by previous steps try to resolv it with mod rewrite (rules with [R=302] parts). But if you need to work on the query string part it will be complex rewrite rules, as could be seen in [Use rewrite rule by query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828938/use-rewrite-rule-by-query-string) or [Rewriting dynamic URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703552/rewriting-dynamic-urls)

Comment: I edited my question with my real codes, so that it will be easier, I have tried your way as you can see in my example. But it is not working too.