# mod_rewrite: replace query_string parameter values

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, query-string

I need to replace the values of the QueryString by using Apache mod_rewrite. Many values have to be replaced by one new value ({oldValueA1, oldValueA2} => newValueA; {oldValueB1, oldValueB2} => newValueB). The parameter appears variable times in the query_string. The order of the parameter values is random. If the redirected query_string contains a value twice, it doesn't matter for me.
The request_uri is variable, but should not be change during the redirect.

Here are some examples. The first row contains the original url, the second the new one.

```
localhost/mag/cat/?myParameter=oldValueA1&myParameter=oldValueB1
localhost/mag/cat/?myParameter=newValueA&myParameter=newValueB

localhost/mag/?myParameter=oldValueA2
localhost/mag/?myParameter=newValueA

localhost/dig/cat/?myParameter=oldValueB1&myParameter=oldValueA2
localhost/dig/cat/?myParameter=newValueB&myParameter=newValueA

localhost/dig/?myParameter=oldValueB2&oldValueB3
localhost/dig/?myParameter=newValueB&newValueB
```

I tried several RewriteRules with some Conditions, but i can't find a solution for this problem. Has anyone an idea?

Thx! :)

Comment: not related: when you have several parameters they should be separated with `&`, not `?`

Comment: rewriting query string parameters is really hard, check this answer for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703552/rewriting-dynamic-urls/7774701#7774701 . As you can see you will have a lot of problems (like working with not yet encoded chars), maybe you could try it in the application code instead of apache/mod_rewrite

Comment: Thx, your right about the ? and &. Copy-paste-mistake. I will change it.

Comment: If you pass localhost/mag/cat/?myParameter=newValueA&myParameter=newValueB, only the last, ie, myParameter=newValueB is passed to your CGI script.

Comment: @jacouh I tested it with the solution in my answer below and both values are passed. It works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. Maybe it will help someone else, too. Here it is:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]|)myParameter=(oldValueA1|oldValueA2)([&?].*|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1myParameter=newValueA [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]|)myParameter=(oldValueB1|oldValueB2)([&?].*|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1myParameter=newValueB [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to include %2 in the rewritecond directive. This will omit any query string parameters after myParameter. Thanks for this!