# Could a manipulated URL cause security issues inside a RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite

I'm brand new to Apache.

I have the following `.htaccess` file

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$ redirect.php?uniqueID=$1 [QSA,L]
```

so that going to: `mySite.com/242skl2j` 

loads the page: `mySite.com/redirect.php?uniqueID=242skl2j`

But let's say I didn't have this RegEx in my Apache code `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and I just allowed for all characters.... could someone load Apache code directly into this by navigating to something like `mySite.com/2%20[R]%20reWriteRule%20^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$%20anything.html@www.aDifferentSite.com/index.html`

Like SQL injection but for Apache? (I'm not even sure `%20` would convert to a space in my apache code but there might be something that can?)

Or is this not really a concern because they can't do any real "harm" to the site, only to their own unique navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no known security hole in Apache where something like this could slip through. Whatever is in your URL gets escaped before it's used inside Apache's engine.

Also, different from those in the central server config, rewrites and redirections defined in `.htaccess` can not "break out" of the current web root*, so even an accidental mis-written (or exploited) `RewriteRule` could not be used to get hold of something that isn't supposed to be served publicly.

<sub>* = see the description of `RewriteRule`'s behaviour in [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).</sub>

Comment: Thankyou :) That's what I was thinking too!

Comment: My main concern wasn't even really security exploits, more so exploits in general... again I'm new to Apache but would it be possible to create a for loop or something in apache that would load a gazillion pages from the server (and eventually crash the server)... If so could someone do that via injection :o

Answer (score 2):

There's not big risks. But there's maybe some things to care a little about.

Usually things handled by mod_rewrite are already **url decoded**. So you could manipulate the HTTP_REFERRER or the query path without any character decoding considerations.

Also the **rewrite rules does not suffer from rules injections**. But you could try it, if you find a way to inject something in a Rule that would be interpreted as a rewriteRule code you would become a rich guy :-). Seriously I don't think you could, theses rules manage arguments as an SQL server would manage arguments when using parameterized queries, parameters cannot be read as code.

But mod_rewrite receive also **the query string part** of the query **before** any urldecode on it. So this is a point where you should be cautious.

Any rule that apply some access restriction based on query string arguments (everything after the `?`), like this [Access Control by Query String](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString#Access_control_by_Query_String) from http://wiki.apache.org is **wrong**:

> Deny access to http://example.com/page?query_string if query_string contains the string foo.
>
> ```
>    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} foo
>    RewriteRule ^/page - [F]
> ```

Using `http://example.com/page?toto=%66oo` with `%66` for `f` would not be detected by mod_rewrite. Managing rules on the query_string part of the request is a very hard stuff. you could check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703552/rewriting-dynamic-urls/7774701#7774701) for examples, usually it means checking for combination of both encoded and decoded characters in the string. But the simple rule is **avoid any access control by mod_rewrite based on the query string, work only on the query path**. And even with paths, double check that using `//` instead of `/` stills works.

In the past some mod_rewrite exploits have existed:

- http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2003-0542 (2003, buffer overflow)
- http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2006-3747 (2006, buffer overflow)
- http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-1862 (2013, bad log escaping)

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. The only thing you need to worry about is how you handle the `uniqueID` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: rewrite rule is nothing more than a replace function, it just replaces what it finds with what you have given it. But since you're passing that to a web application , that may cause a problem if you haven't taken care of incoming data!